# Failed to install node-libssh ... missing v8.h file

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a nodejs application that I'm trying to deploy to my Openshift server. One critical dependency is node-libssh (aka ssh on npm). The installation process requires a compilation, which fails part way through due to missing v8.h file:

```
CC(target) Release/obj.target/libssh/deps/libssh-0.6.4/src/gssapi.o
AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/ssh.a
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ssh/src/nssh.o
    In file included from ../src/nssh.cc:5:
    /opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/include/node/node.h:62:16: error: v8.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/include/node/node.h:67,
             from ../src/nssh.cc:5:
```

I see that we can't install rpm's on our application hosts. Is there any alternate means of making this library file available on the server?

Comment: You can manualy install `libv8-dev` at `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`?

Comment: Woops: Take a look at this: https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-dependency-management.html